# Почему остается лишняя память?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, память

Есть код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define TOTAL_SIZE 1024 * 1024

typedef struct Point
{
    double x;
    double y;
} point_t;

typedef struct Allocator
{
    void dealloc()
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            free(block[i]);
            block[i] = nullptr;
        }

        size = 0;

    }

    void* block[TOTAL_SIZE];
    size_t size = 0;

} alloc;

alloc al;

point_t* createPoint(double x, double y)
{
    point_t* point = (point_t*)malloc(sizeof(point_t));
    point->x = x;
    point->y = y;

    al.block[al.size] = point;
    al.size++;

    return point;
}

point_t* ppp[TOTAL_SIZE];

int main()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < TOTAL_SIZE; i++)
    {
        ppp[i] = createPoint(i, i);
    }

    al.dealloc();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Чтобы отслеживать память, в visual studio можно воспользоваться так называемой Process Memory(ниже есть фото). Я решил заглянуть в него, и увидел, что в самом начале выполнения программы у меня 10,2MB выделено памяти, а в конце 11,1MB, я не понимаю откуда эта разница.

И также почему здесь эта яма?(фото из Process Memory)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой-то винегрет из C и C++. То `Point`, то вдруг `point_t`... Невозможно читать.

Comment: @AnT извиняюсь, исправил

Comment: А почему у вас на графике 75 МБ? Должно быть 10 + 32 МБ.

Comment: @Cerbo я не знаю, больше у меня в коде ничего нет

Comment: ОФТОП. Извините, а что вы пытаетесь сделать? Если пул, так это у вас не пул, а какое-то другое слово.

Comment: @Cerbo я хотел попробовать освободить не по отдельности каждый указатель, а с помощью цикла пройтись, чтобы сразу все освободить, не было цели создать какой-то стандартный аллокатор(как Pool), это чисто для себя

Comment: использование malloc/free в коде на C++ создаст вам проблемы, когда вы перепутаете их и new/delete.

Comment: @gbg вы имеете ввиду, что если у меня в коде будет malloc/free и new/delete одновременно в коде, то будут проблемы?  Можете подробнее описать проблему?

Comment: Когда-то наступит момент, что вы перепутаете и удалите указатель, выделенный new при помощи free и получите UB. Комбинаций перепутывания может быть много.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process Memory показывает память, запрошенную процессом у ОС. Никто вам не обещал, что освобождение ваших объектов `point_t` приведет к возврату всей выделенной памяти обратно в ОС. Теоретически библиотека времени выполнения C/C++ может вообще не возвращать память в ОС, т.е. вы вы можете вообще не увидеть никакого падения графика Process Memory при освобождении памяти через `free`. В вашем случае видно, что какая-то память была возвращена, а какая-то - нет. Любые локальные "впадины", "выпуклости" и прочие особенности формы вашего графика - это не более чем внутренние особенности некоего эвристического алгоритма в библиотеке времени выполнения C/C++, который принимает решение о том, когда и какую память вернуть в ОС.

Попробуйте в своем эксперименте внутри функции `dealloc` освобождать не все выделенные `point_t`, а через один. И вы увидите, что несмотря на то, что половина выделенной памяти была освобождена, Process Memory не уменьшился вообще. Ибо возврата памяти в ОС в таком варианте не происходит.

P.S. В современных реализациях Visual Studio локальный менеджмент динамической памяти реализуется уже большей частью в Windows API, а библиотека времени выполнения является лишь тонкой оболочкой над ним, но суть от этого не меняется.

Comment: Вы в этом уверены? Я думаю, что такой инструмент совершенно не нужен.

Comment: @Cerbo: Оригинально. Команда `top` в Unix вроде бы пока не считается совершенно бесполезной... А инструменты нужны всякие. У этого - свое назначение. Инструментов анализа памяти в Visual Studio много разных.

Comment: А как я буду утечки искать? Вот здесь у ТС провал там метров 5-7 не меньше. Назовите еще другое инструменты анализа.

Comment: @Cerbo: Утечки? Для этого есть Heap Viewer и Memory Snapshot.

Comment: valgrind - не ?

Comment: @Beeen007 Так он вроде на винде не работает?